# Is there asymmetric encryption in SSH?

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature, ssh

I've read in [DigitalOcean article about SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process) that in order for a server to authenticate a client:

> 4. **The server sends the client this encrypted message.**
> 5. **If the client actually has the associated private key, it will be able to decrypt** the message using that key, revealing the original number.

But wasn't it enough for the client to sign the message, why do we need the encryption? Also, given that DSA keys can be used in SSH I'm starting to doubt that the article is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The article is surely wrong.

Nowadays, the sole purpose of client-side private key in SSH is to **sign** messages (as their algorithms are typically ECDSA EdDSA, etc), the server doesn't encrypt the challenge, it almost certainly **verifies** it with the public key(s) in the `authorized_keys` file

Comment: The article's author is probably remembering how it used to work in SSHv1 (which, being RSA-only, _did_ use challenge decryption) and assuming that it still works the same way in SSHv2, which it doesn't.

Comment: @grawity, that's a great remark, thanks!